# How can I set two textboxes in one line for iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, adaptive-design

I use xCode 8.1.
I have two textboxes in one column for iPhone (in portrait mode):
[image: xcode screenshot]

How can I use adaptive design to display these textboxes in one line at iPad and at Landscape mode of iPhone?

Comment: Have you tried with size classes?? Have a look at this: https://makeapppie.com/2016/09/05/an-introduction-to-size-classes-for-xcode-8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position your text boxes as you have shown for portrait

Assuming you want `Name` to stay in the same place, you only need to change the constraints on `Surname`

You should have a TopSpace and a Leading Space defined for `Surname` - select each constraint in turn, and click on the `+` button beside `Installed` - this gives you the option of introducing variations, so click `Add Variation` and then **de**-select the initial default value.

This will mean that these two constraints only apply for iPhones in portrait mode (Compact/Regular

The switch to landscape mode, and position `Surname` where you need it.  Apply constraints - vertical center with `Name` and a Leading spacing.  Select both of those constraints, and repeat the process for creating variations, but they will now be created for iPhone landscape only (Compact/Compact).

Now switch to iPad, and repeat the process you followed for landscape, which will create the iPad constraints (Regular/Regular)

That should be everything you need.  If it doesn't work, or you see red lines in the storyboard, it most likely means you have left one of the `Surname` constraints active for **all** orientations - at the same time as having conflicting constraints for specifics - if you can't find which one, delete the constraints and start again :-)

Here's a screenshot showing where you add the variation

[image]

and here's what it looks like after you have added a portrait-specific constraint
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, Russell

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use a Stack View with varying trait.
Select the two fields in Interface builder and in the bottom right corner press the Stack button.

[image]

Then select the stack view and open attributes inspector tab.
[image]

Add a variation based on width, and for this variation (Regular width) set the axis to be Horizontal.

Done.

Note: Don't go with the stack view if your deployment target is bellow iOS 9.

Comment: Brilliant idea!

Answer (score 0):

The key to doing this in Xcode 8 is the **Vary For Traits** button bottom right of the editor.

- Select an iPad from the *View as* list, and set up your constraints as you would for iPad.
- Then select an iPhone, and click **Vary For Traits**, and select *width*.
- Now, select any constraints that aren't used on the iPhone, and hit delete. This doesn't delete them entirely, it just uninstalls them *for that size class*
- Then add the constraints you need for the iPhone. This only adds constraints for the compact width size class
- When you are done, click *Done Varying*
- et voila…

[[image: Compact width]][[image: enter Regular width]]